# ¿Cómo redirecciónar public_html de un hosting (godaddy) a una carpeta?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirección

Buen dia a todos, tengo una duda y no se como resolverlo. Tengo un hosting en godaddy, y cuando quiero alojar una pagina web desarrollada en Laravel  me aparece que tengo que colocarlo en la carpeta public_html, el problema comienza cuando quiera realizar en un futuro otros proyectos, tendria que agregar una subcarpeta pero a la vez apareciera todo el contenido de la pagina principal y esto generaría un caos por tantos archivos en la raiz. Entonces que deberia hacer para redirigir el public_html a una subcarpeta?

Aqui les dejo el ejemplo de mi dominio principal apuntando a la raiz de la carpeta public_html:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesitaria es que apunte a una subcarpeta para no tener todo los archivos de mi pagina principal volando en la raiz  y lo que necesitaria seria tener todo en una subcarpeta ejemplo/public_html/mipagina1 y esta pueda ser visualizado por el dominio principal, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Public_html es una página o una carpeta? Si es una carpeta, puedes ingresar el directorio del proyecto directamente `public_html/mipagina1/pagina.html` o si en el proyecto cuentas con un archivo index podrías sólo ingresar la subcarpeta `public_html/mipagina1` y esto automáticamente abriría el `index.html`

Comment: Hace tiempo me encontré con este problema. Si son proyectos con dominios diferentes, tienes que crear una subcarpeta en public_html para cada proyecto, de esta manera podrás instalar un gestor de contenidos diferente en cada uno de ellos. Si lo que quieres es crear subdominios, los puedes crear desde el CPanel. Ya dirás!

Comment: De hechos tengo otros dominios y con la herramienta de workpress cree una paginas y me genero una carpeta dentro de public_html. por lo cual del dominio principal  tengo mi pagina principal pero tambien quisiera moverlo en una subcarpeta, asi cuando entre a la carpeta public_html lo que vea sea: carpeta-pagina-1 , carpeta-pagina-2, etec..

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario, si tendrás tu propio dominio `tudominio.com` puedes apuntarlo a `public_html` y para otros proyectos puedes crear subdominios desde el cPanel, por ejemplo: `pagina1.tudominio.com`, `pagina2.tudominio.com` y apuntarlos al directorio que tu elijas incluso si están fuera de `public_html`.

También lo que puedes hacer es tener alojada tu propia página en `public_html` y crear una carpeta que se llame `sitios` por ejemplo, y dentro de ella colocar todos los proyectos para que puedas acceder mediante `tudominio.com/sitios/proyecto1/`, `tudominio.com/sitios/proyecto2/`, y si estos proyectos tendrán su propio dominio, no habrá problema para cuando lo registres y lo apuntes a su carpeta correspondiente.

Comment: Pero lo que quiero es no tener el contenido de  mi pagina en la raiz de la carpeta public_html, los otros proyectos con sus dominios si los tengo dentro de su respectiva subcarpeta dentro de public_html, bueno eso lo hizo workpresss automatico